# res.redirect not working after the page is rendered with data

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express, ejs

I have a simple functionality of forget password, that when user requests for change in password he recieves an email with token and his email on clicking of it he will be redirected to a page which will take his new passwords.

What I do is when I click on a link in the email , server gets the request and a function take data out of the link renders the page with data (using res.render) and then it should redirect to the rendered page.

The problem I am facing is when I click on link I am getting data and page rendered but I can't let res.redirect() to work.

my link looks like this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/resetpassword?_csrf=ab8aa6a41567f817330e3e0a214725f8b2f88b487d5bef16f162e033c6a63dc41933511ddb79cb44ca049f472b3e0c593dbbaf&email=dummyEmail%2540dumyurl.ca
```

And then I get the request on server using app.get().

```
app.get('/api/resetpassword', Admin.resetPasswordPage);
```

and my rendering and redirecting function looks like this;

```
resetPasswordPage: function (req, res, next) {
    req.query.email = decodeURIComponent(req.query.email) ;
    res.render('resetPassword', {
        Email: req.query.email,
        Csrf : req.query._csrf,

    }, function (err, html) {
        console.log("TESTING HTML ", html);
        if (!err)
        res.redirect("/resetPassword");
    });
}
```

Rendering is successful as I am getting complete HTML of the page in the html parameter, but the question is how to redirect to that page. That page is made in EJS and its in views folder.

Comment: So when I removed /api from URL, it redirects me correctly to the page but web page is not loader an error comes in the browser 
`This web page has a redirect loop`

Comment: hi Suleman, i'm also building a forget password function like yours. do you have git i can reference from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want this flow:

1. User clicks link to `/api/resetpassword...`
2. express runs the `resetPasswordPage` function
3. `resetPasswordPage` responds with the reset password form HTML page, pre-filled out based on the query parameters
4. I think at this point you don't like the URL in the browser address bar, which is why you think you need a redirect. But you need those query string parameters, and if you do a redirect to just `/resetPassword`, you'll lose them. So you either have to live with the URL (which I would recommend as it's the simplest) or rely on session state and the session cookie. However, marking the session with something like `passwordResetOK=true` probably exposes you to a whole bunch of CSRF attacks that the `_csrf` query string parameter is there to prevent.
5. You don't need any redirect here, the browser has the form. Next step is for the user to fill out the form and submit it with `<form method="post" action="/resetPassword">`
6. Browser does `POST /resetPassword`
7. express routes that to another function that changes the password and then either sends back a success page or redirects to the home page or whatever

So long story short is I think you just need to accept the URL being what it is and you don't need a redirect in here until after the password reset operation completes.

Comment: Peter Thanks for your reply, yes that is the scenario I am following, when I removed the /api from the URL I was redirected to the page, but browser gave an error `This web page has a redirect loop`

Comment: Write down the sequence you want to see including each HTTP request your app is supposed to receive and each corresponding HTTP response you intend to send, and what the browser does with each response. A redirect loop is a pretty straightforward error in your programming sequence that you should be able to think threw and fix on your own. Go slow, take notes, think carefully, and you'll be able to fix the loop get things working.

Comment: Yeah 25 mins of intense thought processing solved the problem thanks.